# How to render Image with title and content dynamically?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, ejs

I have created title and content that is dynamically inserted but I want to add an image between the title and the content but I could not find a way

***in my controller***

```js
const postSchema = {
  title: String,
  content: String,

};

const Post = mongoose.model("Post", postSchema);

app.get("/", function(req, res){

  Post.find({}, function(err, posts){
    res.render("home", {
      posts: posts
      });

  });
});
```

***and my ejs***

**

```
<h3><%=post.title%></h3>

<p>
<%=post.content.substring(0, 200) + " ..."%>
<a href="/posts/<%=post._id%>">Read More</a>
</p>
```

I expect the output of:

**Title**

**image**

**content.**

Comment: Where is image field in you schema. Add image field into schema, save that image there or its url and when you fetch it you will get your image in your data too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the image src to the schema.

```
const postSchema = {
    title: String,
    content: String,
    url: String,
    altText: String
};
```

Then use the image tag.

```
<Img src="<%=post.url%>" alt="<%=post.altText%>"/>
```